# How to change recipient on Postfix relay (smtp_generic_maps not working)?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I have a Postfix mail gateway setup and would like to change the recipient address. I want all mail being relayed for `ceo@yahoo.com` to instead by relayed to `ceo@somewhere.org` I have Postfix configured using `smtp_generic_maps` (as below) however this only works for mail being generated on the Postfix server itself.  Any mail being relayed through the Postfix server still goes to `ceo@yahoo.com` effectively ignoring `smtp_generic_maps`. What configuration should I look into to accomplish this?

```
# grep smtp_generic_maps main.cf
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic

# postmap /etc/postfix/generic
# service postfix reload

# cat /etc/postfix/generic
ceo@yahoo.com               ceo@somewhere.org
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You shouldn't use `smtp_generic_maps` for this

The [Postfix Address Rewriting Readme](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#generic) describes the correct use for `smtp_generic_maps`:

> With the `smtp_generic_maps` parameter you can specify [generic(5)](http://www.postfix.org/generic.5.html) lookup
>   tables that replace local mail addresses by valid Internet addresses
>   when mail leaves the machine via SMTP. The [generic(5)](http://www.postfix.org/generic.5.html) mapping replaces
>   envelope and header addresses, and is non-recursive. It does not
>   happen when you send mail between addresses on the local machine.

You are trying to use it (instead of replacing local addresses like `ceo@localdomain.local`) for replacing an address with FQDN `ceo@yahoo.com`. As `yahoo.com` is not configured in `mydestination` it is not considered as a local domain, thus not processed by [generic(5)](http://www.postfix.org/generic.5.html) mapping.

However, you should not configure a domain of someone else as a local domain as it really should be handled by [smtp(8)](http://www.postfix.org/smtp.8.html) delivery agent instead. Doing so would prevent any user sending mail to any `@yahoo.com` address. That kind of tampering would be technically incorrect and maybe even illegal.

---

### Leading users towards company policy by `check_recipient_access`

If the problem is that someone is trying to email your CEO to a personal `@yahoo.com` address and you would like to prevent that and force using company email `ceo@example.com` instead, you could add a `check_recipient_access` restriction to your `main.cf`:

```
 smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
     ...
     check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/denied_recipients,
     ...
     permit
```

and then add a reject with a human readable reason into `/etc/postfix/denied_recipients`:

```
 ceo@yahoo.com  REJECT  The CEO must be contacted using official <ceo@example.com> address.
```

(As I used `hash:` in my example, don't forget to `postmap /etc/postfix/denied_recipients`.)

---

### Using [transport(5)](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) table for overriding Postfix built-in defaults

In order to make all `ceo@yahoo.com` be delivered to `ceo@example.com` you can use `transport_maps` instead of `smtp_generic_maps`.

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The   optional  [transport(5)](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html)  table  specifies  a  mapping  from  email
>   addresses to message delivery  transports  and  next-hop  destinations.
>   Message  delivery  transports  such as local or smtp are defined in the
>   `master.cf` file, and next-hop destinations are typically hosts or domain
>   names. The table is searched by the [trivial-rewrite(8)](http://www.postfix.org/trivial-rewrite.8.html) daemon.
>
> This  mapping overrides the default `transport:nexthop` selection that is
>   built into Postfix.

Add `transport_maps` to your `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
 transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

And then add to `/etc/postfix/transport` one line for `ceo@yahoo.com` altering the default `transport:nexthop` to `virtual:ceo@example.com`:

```
 ceo@yahoo.com   virtual:ceo@example.com
 yahoo.com       :
 *               :
```

The other lines just states that no modification is done for `yahoo.com` and the rest, falling back to the default `transport:nexthop` behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as to why `smtp_generic_maps` are not working however I am still stuck as to how to re-write the recipient address when relaying. I thought this would be easy to do with postfix, however it's looking more like a procmail or maildrop solution now.

Comment: Your generic map starts to work as soon as you add `yahoo.com` in `mydestination`. However, like warned, that will brake all mail to that domain by making all `user@yahoo.com` to local mailboxes available in local delivery and replying `550 5.1.1` aka `User unknown in local recipient table` for all other yahoo.com addresses.

Comment: Hrm.. I was going to use an entry in `transports`; eg; `ceo@yahoo.com   procmail` and then add local `ceo` user with a `~/.procmailrc`.  I did not consider  `mydestination = ...,yahoo.com`.  Not sure the transports approach will work.. still testing

Comment: You were simultaneously heading to the same direction I was trying to guide you in my additional solution! Now my answer describes why the original suggestion didn't work and two different approaches.

Comment: Is it necessary to include `yahoo.com :` and `*`? Can we exclude both or include only `*`?

Comment: No, neither is required (as told with "The other lines just states...").